# Executing DB2 commands '' db2start: command not found ''

Tags: centos, db2, nagios, db2-luw, dbd

I have one virtual server running on centos7. I configure it for the Nagios monitoring tool. I created the config file etc. I have 9 DB instances. When I migrated the DB config file with Nagios(adding to the Nagios )

I saw this error code on http://mysiteipaddr/nagios

> CRITICAL - cannot connect to db.ipaddress.com. install_driver(DB2) failed: Can't locate DBD/DB2.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/nagios/libexec /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at (eval 10) line 3.

After this error, I realize the DB2 is not installed on my machine. I've installed the DB2 drivers and when I execute this command I'm facing this output.

```
 db2ls
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/opt/ibm/db2/V9.7                11.1.1.1        1                            Fri Jan 31 11:33:28 2020 +03             0
[root@backup ~]#
```

But when I want to execute DB2 command like `db2start`, `db2stop`, `db2status`, it won't execute and I got this error code.

```
bash: db2stop: command not found 
bash: db2start:command not found
```

Comment: Have you "source"d the Db2 environment? There is a script to include into bashrc or profile

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the full name of the Db2 driver that you installed?  For example: the Db2 runtime client,  or the ODBC and jdbc client, or the full Db2 client?   The `db2start` command is part of the *Db2-server*. It's not necessary to start a Db2-client, but *depending on which Db2-client* you installed you may need to dot in its db2profile , or at the very least, the client's binaries directory has to be on the PATH for the account that runs nagios before you start nagios.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your kindly helps mao.

When I execute " db2ls -p -q -b /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/" output shows me this.

Product Response File ID                  Level   Fix Pack   Product Description
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXPRESS_C                               11.1.1.1          1   DB2 Express-C

Comment: Learn how to edit your question. Learn how to describe your environment. Are all 9 Db2-instances up and running? Are they local or remote (relative to nagios)? Are you using a different Db2-instance for nagios, and have you dotted in its instance-profile for the account that runs nagios?  Do not give answers in comments, they get lost, but instead EDIT your question with new facts.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an instance created? run /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/instance/db2ilist

Comment: Yes, I created a instance name "tobe".

Comment: Thanks, @Vicki Chen. In my case, there was no instance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the folder /home/tobe/sqllib/adm for db2start and db2stop commands. You can also define an alias if you want to call them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Install below package in all of the instances:

`yum -y install perl-CPAN`

hope so this will be helpful for you....!!!!